# HTML5 Drag drop in IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-10

Consider [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yubms/):

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:red" draggable="true" />
```

In IE10, when I move the red box around, it shows the cursor with a small circle with a line through it:

[image]

On the other hand, in IE10 testdrive's [fridge demo](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/MagneticPoetry/Default.html), when we drag the magnets, it shows a hand with + sign.

Besides setting `draggable` to true, what else is required to make the cursor show the correct shape?

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate that you accept the drop, by cancelling the dragover event. So for the element that you can drop onto, listen for the ondragover event, and cancel it.

A bit late with this answer but hopefully that is all you need.